# How do I analyse the output of this code with the struct

Tags: c++, struct, constructor

So I got this piece of code of with I must determine the output, but I have no idea how to start. Could somebody please tell me step by step what happens? 
The line `S(int V, S*...)` and the line `S s = S(10, new...)` confuse me the most.

I do have a rough knowledge about pointers and classes, but obviously not enough.

I know what `S* n` means and what `s.n -> n`, but `S s` confuses me

I tried following the code step by step but got lost at line `S(int V, S* N....)`

```
struct S {
    S* n;
    int v;
    S(int V, S* N) : n(N), v(V) {};
};

S s = S(10, new S(20, &s));
std::cout << (s.n->n->v);
```

The output is `10` but I don't know why.

Comment: Please don't link to code. Put all relevant code *in* the question - as *text*.

Comment: Do you understand what is `s`? what is `s.n`? What is `s.n->n`? How many object do we have?

Comment: how does this even compile? You are passing pointer `s` as `&s`

Comment: @TarickWelling, `s` is not a pointer. The code is "fine".

Comment: @Jarod42 Thats all that was given, it was an old exam question

Comment: @YvesBetschmann: question was for you. what do you understand, what do you don't understand?

Comment: @Jarod42 I know what S* n means and what s.n -> n, but S s confuses me

Comment: Do you understand `int i = 42;`? `S s = /*..*/;` is the same. Definition of `s` of type `S`.

Comment: The tricky part is `&s` which is the `s` under construction. but relatively intuitive anyway. `s` is uninitialized, but `&s` have sense.

Comment: `S s` is the simplest part of the code!

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, the S s part is clear, but the new S(10, &s) i find weird, and also the n(N), v(V) {};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at the code line per line:

```
Struct S {
   // ...
};
```

This creates a structure named `S`.
Inside there are two variables (members of the structure):

```
S* n;
int v;
```

To create an object of type `S`, you have defined a "constructor":

```
S(int V, S* N) : n(N), v(V) {};
```

which takes an integer and a pointer to a structure `S`, which both are directly assigned to the members of the object created.

---

Then, in the main part of the code:

```
S s = S(10, new S(20, &s));
```

The object `s` is created.
Inside, the integer `v` is equal to 10, and you can access with `s.v`.
There is also `n`, a pointer to a structure `S`, accessible with `s.n`.

This `n` has also two parameters, this time accessible with `->` due to it being a pointer.

- `s.n->v` is assigned to be 20.
- `s.n->n` is assigned to be a pointer to `s`, previously defined.

So you can simplify `s.n->n` to a pointer to `s`.

Thus printing:

```
std::cout << (s.n->n->v);
```

is equivalent to

```
std::cout << s.v;
```

and the answer is `10`.

Comment: Thanks alot! Could you also explain what the n(N) and v(V) stands for?

Comment: Welcome :) 
I can try to explain: the lowercase v is the member of the structure S, and the uppercase V is the parameter given during the construction. (10 and 20 in your example). Writing v(V), copy the value of V inside v, and it the same explanation for n(N).
You can learn more in this page: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/

Comment: So to evaluate the output I must find s.n and to find s.n I must find the Pointer N, meaning evaluating new S(20, &s) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
struct S{
        S* n
        int v;
        S(int V, S* N): n(N), v(V){};
        };

S s = S(10,new S(20,&s));
cout << (s.n->n->v);
```

s.n give you the s in the left side of the "=", then the ->n give you the (S* n) the struct from the S(20,&s) that is the same s that have value 10, and the ->v returns the value 10

Answer (score 0):

The first confusing line is just a constructor that initializes `struct` members with its arguments like this:

```
struct S {
    S* n;  // <-- N goes here
    int v; // <-- V goes here
    S(int V, S* N) : n(N), v(V) {};
};
```

The second confusing line is constructing two objects of type `S`, let's break it down:

```
//       this goes to s1.v
//       |
//       |   this goes to s1.n
//       v   v~~~~~~~~~~~~~
S s1 = S(10, new S(20, &s1));
//           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//           let's call this s2
```

and now `s1.n == s2` and `s2->n == &s1`, which is why `s1.n->n == &s1` and `s1.n->n->v == 10`.

Comment: minor nitpick: `s1.n == &s2`, `s2->n == &s1`, and `s1.n->n == &s1`

Comment: or be consistent with `s1` being an instance and `s2` being a pointer in the code